# how to split a comma separated line in bash

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
2017-06-01,3967485,Completed,local,in,0,13492,11746,2017-06-27 14:13:47+00,2017-06-27 14:20:16+00,389,ddb19040,mydomain.net,yourdomain.net,""
2017-07-01,3967488,Completed,local,in,0,13492,11746,2017-07-27 14:13:47+00,2017-06-27 14:20:16+00,389,ddb19040,mydomain.net,yourdomain.net,""
```

What I need to do is write a bash script that will loop through this file line by line, and grab the first field as one value, and then save the rest of the line without the first field (and comma) as a separate variable.

I have the following code so far:

```
 for aline in $(cat /tmp/test.csv); do                         
       echo $aline 
 done
```

But i'm not sure how to parse each line. 
Any pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT1

Using the suggested answer produces the following output in new_file

```
   ,Completed,local,in,0,13492,11746,2017-06-27 14:13:47+00,2017-06-27 14:20:16+00,389,ddb19040,mydomain.net,yourdomain.net,""
   ,Completed,local,in,0,13492,11746,2017-07-27 14:13:47+00,2017-06-27 14:20:16+00,389,ddb19040,mydomain.net,yourdomain.net,""
```

I'd like it to include field2 ($b in the suggested answer) at the start of each line

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Please post your expected output. I'm not sure what you mean by `grab… as one value, and… as a separate variable`.

Comment: But `,Completed...` is the third column to the rest!

Answer (score 2):

How about using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}{$1=""; print}' file_name
```

Comment: so do this after the echo ?

Comment: @dot - no need for anything except this simple one line. Just replace `file_name` with your file, eg `/tmp/test.csv` and you're off to the races. If your input is huge, you'll also notice that this solution is much more computationally efficient than using bash (ie. it will finish faster)

Comment: @dot - did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
while IFS=, read -r a b; do echo "$b" >> new_file; done < file
cat new_file
```

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: so that almost works except that new_file is missing field 2... and starts with a comma.  will update my original question with the sample outupt so you can see

Comment: POST edited, try again please

Answer (score 0):

```
$ IFS=,
$ while  read -r a b ;do onevalue=$a; restvalue=$b; echo $a ;done <CSV_FILE >FirstF
$ cat FirstF
2017-06-01
2017-07-01
```

put your processing code for the rest value by making use of $b variable inside loop block one val for each one loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed

```
sed 's/[^,]*,//' csv.file
```

If you want to keep the first col in a file

```
sed -e 'h;s/,.*//w col1.file' -e 'x;s/[^,]*,//' csv.file
```

Or with gnu sed

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/;W col1.file' -e 's/[^\n]*\n//' csv.file
```